# Java 8 keytool is not using -providerName option correctly

Tags: java, security, keytool, jce

I have found that, when using [keytool (windows, Java 8 u45)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/keytool.html#keytool_option_certreq) to generate a csr from an EC keypair, stored in a keystore and using a custom provider specified via `-providerName`, that, the csr is not signed using algorithm I've specified from *my* provider (the provider it seems, is only working to specify the keystore).  Why, when I've told the tool what to use, would it only use it for "some" operations?  I've got it to work by listing my provider as the default provider in java.security, but, it makes little sense to me that I should have to do that when I've explicitly told the tool to "use this provider".

Is this a bug in the program, or a bug in my understanding?

Comment: Well, reading the [documentation of keytool](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/keytool.html) I really could not tell what the "provider*" parameters are exactly doing (used solely for the keystore or also the algorithms). So, obviously you got the empirical answer...

Comment: Well, yeah... LOL... but, should it work as one would expect (give it a provider to use and expect it to be used) or just used for "select" things, which are not documented?  I think this is a bug in the tool... otherwise, why not let the tool just locate whatever provider it likes?

Comment: If one would read the documentation in the way the tool works (according to your observation), it simply uses the specified provider for the keystore type to load and the standard JCE convention to search for algorithm implementations starting at the first registered provider. But I got your point. I'm working with the JCE for years and never cared about this, but IMHO the documentation could be improved here.